# About $T \circ S$ and its representation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $V$ be a vector space, $\dim V=n$. Let $T,S:V \to V$ be linear transformations.

Suppose $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $T \circ S$, prove that $Ker(S \circ T) \ne 0$.

---

Let $B$ be a basis for $V$. Note that $[T \circ S]_B^B=[T]_B^B[S]_B^B$

0 is an eigenvalue of $T \circ S$, so it it an eigenvalue of $[T \circ S]_B^B$, so $\Bbb{nul}[T \circ S]_B^B= \Bbb{nul}[T]_B^B[S]_B^B \ne 0$.

So $\Bbb{rank}([T]_B^B[S]_B^B)<n$.

What can I say about the rank of $[S]_B^B[T]_B^B$ in that case? Is it also less then $n$? Why?

Thanks!

Comment: There's an approach with determinants and one without them. With determinants, note that $\det ST = \det TS$. Without, note that if we had $\operatorname{rk}  ST = n$, then $S$ and $T$ would both need to be invertible, which would in turn imply that $TS$ was invertible.

Comment: @Anonymous Great, thanks!